# How can I use select2 inside uikit uk-dropdown?

Tags: jquery, uikit, jquery-select2

When I have used select2 dropdown inside uk-dropdown [Uikit](https://getuikit.com/docs/dropdown) and selected one option it automatically closed the modal.

Here is the codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nakumdilip/pen/LYNRojo)

```js
// In your JavaScript code (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="button">Click</button>
    <div uk-dropdown="mode:click">
        sfsdf
        <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            ...
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>

        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because uikit tend to steal focus from other elements outside of the uikit. Since by default, Select2 attaches the dropdown menu to the  element, it is considered "outside of uikit".

To avoid this problem, you may attach the dropdown to the uikit itself with the dropdownParent setting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
        dropdownParent: $("#placeholder")
    });
});
```

**Working code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#placeholder")
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/css/uikit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.js"></script>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<button class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="button">Click</button>
<div id="placeholder" uk-dropdown="mode:click">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
     It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
   
</div>
```